# Get specific data from a .json file and save them to a 2D matrix/dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, processing

I am new at python and I have been trying to do some NLP on various .json files inside a folder. I have managed to get and print separately every entry from the dictionary using the key which is article get the description value. The thing is every time the loop executes I save the new data value to the same variable which is body1. What I find for some reason particularly difficult to do is save each data entry (each articles description) in a  two dimensional matrix or a table of dictionaries if you which in order to be able to have all the entries there for future use. Something like :

body1 = ['file_name', 'description', 
         'file_name', 'description',
         'file_name', 'description']
So if I need I will be able to print the second file's description using body1[name][description]. Now in every iteration the data from the last iteration are lost. I think that my C-configured was of thinking does now let me see the answer to that. I would appreciate any ideas.

Thank you in advance,
George

```
   import os
   import glob
   import json
   import nltk
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords
   from nltk import PorterStemmer

   stop = stopwords.words('english')
   stemmer=PorterStemmer()

   for name in glob.glob('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/test/*'):
     jfile = open(name, 'r')
     values = json.load(jfile)
     jfile.close()
     body1 = values['article']['description']
     tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(body1)
     tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
     vocab = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop]
     print body1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ceate a list outside the loop and append the values.

```
final = [] # add values you want saved to final
uniq_ident = 1
for name in glob.glob('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/test/*'):
     jfile = open(name, 'r')
     values = json.load(jfile)
     jfile.close()
     body1 = values['article']['description']
     tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(body1)
     tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
     vocab = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop]
     final.append([uniq_ident,vocab]) # append vocab or whatever values you want to keep
     uniq_ident += 1
     print body1
```

You can also use make final a dict with `final = {}` and use  `final[uniq_ident] = vocab`

If you want to keep final a list and append a dict each time use:

```
 final.append({uniq_ident:vocab})
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I tried that and got this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vocab.py", line 19, in <module>
    tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(body1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/regexp.py", line 133, in tokenize
    return self._regexp.findall(text)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: sorry, what values are you trying to keep? I edited the code, whatever values you want to save append them to final. Anything you assign in the for loop will be overwritten each time

Comment: The .json format is this:
{
    "article": {
     "description": "some text",
    }
}

And I want to have the description part of every article in a table where the 1 entry will be row: filename and column:description. I tried what you suggested without the tokenizer and the result was:
[description1, description2, description3 etc]. I need to have the article name or a unique id as reference. I think I need 2 for loops
in order to create such a 2D structure. Another thing could be having each row as a dictionary entry like : [filename1:description1, filename2:description2, etc].

Comment: That worked yeah! Thank you so much. I just need a way to be able to do the referencing I mentioned using a unique id like 1,2,3 for each file or ideally that reference could be the file's name. Thanks a lot mate !

Comment: no worries, you can use a count variable increasing each time through the loop and append that also for a uniques identifier if you wanted.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought about that and to tell you the truth in C will be some kind of body1=[count][description]. The thing is I can't make it work in python. I really thank you a lot for your help so far but if you have any ideas on how to make that happen it will be massively appreciated.

Comment: I added a couple of extra bits, just an idea of how to use a dict and create a unique number for each

Comment: Great! Thanks for the insight. One last think if you are aware of course. Do you know if I can use that uniq_id as a key in a matrix whose each data entry is a dictionary entry? I mean if you believe that this could be done relatively easy. Something like :
body1 = [uniq_id: description1, uniq_id+1, description2 etc]

Comment: You can store anything in a python list